# SQL Server heap v.s. clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, heap, clustered-index, heap-table

I am using SQL Server 2008. I know if a table has no clustered index, then it is called heap, or else the storage model is called clustered index (B-Tree).

I want to learn more about what exactly means heap storage, what it looks like and whether it is organized as "heap" data structure (e.g. minimal heap, maximum heap). Any recommended readings? I want to more a bit more internals, but not too deep. :-)

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Heap storage has nothing to do with [these heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

Heap just means records themselves are not ordered (i. e. not linked to one another).

When you insert a record, it just gets inserted into the free space the database finds.

#### Updating a row in a heap based table does not affect other records (though it affects secondary indexes)

If you create a secondary index on a `HEAP` table, the `RID` (a kind of a physical pointer to the storage space) is used as a row pointer.

Clustered index means that the records are part of a `B-Tree`. When you insert a record, the `B-Tree` needs to be relinked.

#### Updating a row in a clustered table causes relinking of the B-Tree, i. e. updating internal pointers in other records.

If you create a secondary index on a clustered table, the value of the clustered index key is used as a row pointer.

This means a clustered index should be unique. If a clustered index is not unique, a special hidden column called `uniquifier` is appended to the index key that makes if unique (and larger in size).

It is also worth noting that creating a secondary index on a column makes the values or the clustered index's key to be the part of the secondayry index's key.

#### By creating an index on a clustered table, you in fact always get a composite index

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_mytable_1234 (col1, col2, col3, col4)

CREATE INDEX IX_mytable_5678 (col5, col6, col7, col8)
```

Index `IX_mytable_5678` is in fact an index on the following columns:

```
col5
col6
col7
col8
col1
col2
col3
col4
```

This has one more side effect:

#### A `DESC` condition in a single-column index on a clustered table makes sense in `SQL Server`

This index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_mytable ON mytable (col1)
```

can be used in a query like this:

```
SELECT  TOP 100 *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
       col1, id
```

, while this one:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_mytable ON mytable (col1 DESC)
```

can be used in a query like this:

```
SELECT  TOP 100 *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
       col1, id DESC
```

Comment: So, is inserting a row into a heap faster/slower/same as inserting a row into a B-Tree?

Comment: Inserting into a heap is *a little bit* faster than that to a `B-Tree` if no page split occurs on the latter, and *much* faster if the page split occurs (i. e. there is no place to enter the new row and the data should be redistributed between the leaves).

Comment: Damn you're good, Quassnoi... you know how much garbage exists on the net regarding Clustered indexes...

Comment: From what I understand, it's not that the nonclustered index also indexes the clustered key, it's that the leaf nodes in the secondary index *contain* the clustered key. It's like the nonclustered have an implicit `INCLUDE` clause with the entire clustered key. This is why having a small clustered key is important for performance.  If you have a large clustered key, the leaf nodes of the nonclustered index are much larger, so it takes more I/O to load the index pages.

Comment: @PaulWilliams: this is only true for unique non-clustered indexes. If the non-clustered index is not unique, it contains the cluster keys (and the uniquifier if it's used) in the branch pages as well.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Do you have any references to back up your point about non-unique, non-clustered indexes containing the clustered key in root and intermediate index pages? The official Microsoft Documentation is not very clear on the subject (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484(v=sql.105).aspx). I can understand why they would want to include the clustered index in the root and intermediate pages, but  why would the index being unique make any difference?

Comment: @MartinBrown: how else would SQL Server track the back mapping (from the table to index), in order say to delete or update records? See this old discussion of mine with Paul White: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/Topic714684-1545-6.aspx

Answer (score 11):

Heaps are just tables without a clustering key - without a key that enforces a certain physical order.

I would not really recommend having heaps at any time - except maybe if you use a table temporarily to bulk-load an external file, and then distribute those rows to other tables.

In every other case, I would strongly recommend using a clustering key. SQL Server will use the Primary Key as the clustering key by default - which is a good choice, in most cases. UNLESS you use a GUID (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) as your primary key, in which case using that as your clustering key is a horrible idea.

See Kimberly Tripp's excellent blog posts [GUIDs as Primary and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) and [The Clustered Index Debate Continues](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) for excellent explanations why you should always have a clustering key, and why a GUID is a horrible clustering key.

My recommendation would be:

- in 99% of all cases try to use a `INT IDENTITY` as your primary key and let SQL Server make that the clustering key as well
- exception #1: if you're bulk loading huge data amounts, you might be fine without a primary / clustering key for your temporary table
- exception #2: if you must use a GUID as your primary key, then set your clustering key to a different column - preferably a `INT IDENTITY` - and I would even create a separate INT column just for that purpose, if no other column can be used

Marc

Answer (score 0):

[Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188270.aspx) is the best source!

The whole *Database Engine - Planning and Architecture - Tables and Index Data Structures Architecture* is very good internal introduction.

[From this link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=765433f7-0983-4d7a-b628-0a98145bcb97&DisplayLang=en) you can download a local copy of Books Online(it is free). It is the best (and official) reference to all Sql 2008 questions.